# Nginx + Yii app = js,css - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, nginx, yii

I've got a mayday situation. 
I moved from apache to nginx on a new server, setupped nginx+php-fpm+mariadb.

Now besides errors with MVC-structure, which jumped outta nowhere, there is another bug - Chrome console filled with red - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on connections to jpg and css files.

What can it be? Is it an error in assets Yii Component or it is in NGINX config?
Here is mine configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name    example.ru; 
    root  /var/www/sites/example.ru; 

    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
       deny  all;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
                fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
                if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
                    set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
                }

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;


                fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
    }

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }

    location ~ \.js {
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
    }
```

}

.htaccess is almost blank

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

Comment: Check again the whole url that get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  and double check that server and port are right ones. The only thing that makes sense for me is that your are conecting to somewhere wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to enable SSL on my NGINX server after moving to new one and all scripts server was searching were starting with 'https://'.